# Different REST-ful representations of the same Entity and content negotiation

Tags: xml, rest, content-negotiation

Given the REST-ful web service

```
/product/{product-id}
```

that returns Product XML documents of the Content-Type

```
x-esvc/product+xml
```

I also need to support

```
x-esvc/prices+xml
```

(x-esvc is a custom MIME type; product and prices are two subtypes and +xml is a hint that it is an XML based format as per [RFC 3023](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3023.txt))

The question is whether this second format should be have its own web service

```
/prices/{product-id}
```

... or whether I should use content negotiation and the Accept HTTP header to differentiate between the two formats in the existing product web service?

Please note that there is only one real entity involved (Product) and that "prices" is a list of dependent objects in OO terms. The same identifier can, however, be used in both cases.

Another way to formulate the issue is whether "prices" could be considered a different representation of the same resource or if it should be considered another resource given that the information is different?

I do know that content negotiation is typically used to differentiate between different technical formats like JPG and PNG for the same image; i.e. the information is the same but the format is different. In this case content negotiation would be used to differentiate between different information for the same entity.

Would this be a valid use of Content Negotiation and the Accept HTTP header in a REST-ful web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd favor different web services. it simplifies the use by any consumer as the request can be expressed completely by specifying the url alone. this might be irrelevant at the current stage of your project but might change as it evolves - it's easier to assemble and maintain web service calls without having to fiddle around with request headers.

if you don't need/want this separation server-side you can still unify the two url locations by directives in your web server configuration.

operating the web service might also become easier: think load balancing and maintenance downtime.

depending on your project's scale, your mileage may vary. for some in-house PoC you probably best cling to what you have.

Comment: I ended up with the same conclusion, using different web services is better. Actually I now believe the entity and resource concepts should be kept separate, i.e. we can have multiple resources for the same entity and all resources should have their own, unique URI although they all refer to the same entity.